# Infiniband QDR to DDR

Tags: infiniband

I have a bunch of computer with onboard Mellanox ConnectX-2 QDR Infiniband 40Gbps Controllers. They have QSFP connectors.

I have a switch with 24 4x CX4 DDR connectors.

If I buy QSFP to CX4 cables, will the QDR controllers on the computers be able to downscale to DDR, and be able to communicate with (through) the switch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infiniband should be smart enough to negotiate a compatible data rate; in your case, since your switch is a DDR switch, your IB network will run at DDR rates.

Comment: Well, I have alot banking on this, so I'd like more than a "should". But thank you for your answer. I'll try to give mellanox a call, and leave this thread in case anyone else can answer.

Comment: Update:

I called mellanox and they verified that QDR can downscale to DDR. Success :D now all I need are QSFP to CX4 cables.

Comment: Just another update, I got the IB working in fedora using the OFED package from the OFED site.